# Joomla table cut off

Tags: php, joomla

I'm running a PHP script in Jumi in a Joomla article that outputs html code for a table, given some fancy pants through a CSS file. The problem is that the table is cut off mid-point for some users, I see the whole thing. I'm new to web development, what could be the reason?

Comment: Needs much, much more detail. Where is the code stored? If in a database, how large is the column? Where is is output from? What does the HTML look like? Is anything else cut off? What browsers does this happen in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask questions about what OS, Web Browser, and Plugins are installed.  Recreate their environment on your end and try to reproduce the problem.  If you can reproduce it, then debug and fix.  If you cant reproduce the problem, then you need to deal more deeply with your clients / users.